# Page Methods and Security

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, security

Recently I learned that you can take a script manager and set the EnablePageMethods="true" this is something I would like to do but is there any security implications ?

Also, Is there a newer better way to this ?

Comment: The security implications would be the same as if you put those methods in a web service.

Comment: Just FYI pagemethods don't work on usercontrols :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All that `EnablePageMethods="true"` really does is generate an inline JavaScript proxy that allows for calling back to `ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods` via the `PageMethods` syntax.

I prefer using jQuery via its `.ajax()` method to call `ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods`, like this:

Code-behind

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetDate()
{
    return DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "PageName.aspx/GetDate",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {
        // Do something interesting here.
    }
});
```

Note: Since `ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods` automatically serialize their response to `JSON`, then `"json"` is the return `dataType` of the AJAX call. `contentType` describes what you are sending to the server.

Comment: Why do you prefer .ajax way ? More control ?

Comment: Yes, I prefer jQuery .ajax because it offers more control and the `PageMethods` syntax has more of an RPC (Remote Procedure Call) feel to it, where I have to specify extra parameters as callbacks for success and error. I am also not a huge fan of JavaScript blocks just being injected into the page. I probably feel this way because I have moved towards more development with ASP.NET MVC versus ASP.NET WebForms.

Comment: Yes, and if you want to know more about why the methods need to be `static` then read [Why do ASP.NET AJAX page methods have to be static?](http://encosia.com/why-do-aspnet-ajax-page-methods-have-to-be-static/)

Answer (score 3):

It does not have any more security implications than would adding any ordinary web page or service to a website.  The needed precautions are the same -- don't use any inputs without validating them first, don't inadvertently return sensitive information in error messages, etc.

There is a newer way, and arguably better, if you don't mind switching to a new platform: [ASP.Net MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc), and the related "Web API".  ([You can use Web API with Webforms also](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/using-web-api-with-aspnet-web-forms), thanks to Karl Anderson for noting in the comments.)

Comment: @MicahArmantrout Then there's nothing new & improved over ASP.Net AJAX, so far as I know.

Comment: Just for clarification you can use `ASP.NET Web API` with WebForms as well. Check out [Using Web API with ASP.NET Web Forms](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/using-web-api-with-aspnet-web-forms)

Comment: @KarlAnderson that's a plus, I did not know that!